Reset supervisor with PGOOD of other supplies
I'm attempting to use Resetn of some IC device of TI that sense 4 voltages and after some threshold the IC output release the ResetN, but I'm afraid that it is not enough and I want to ensure the voltage with PGOOD of every power supplies, is it possible? the Pgood is open drain the sense input voltage of Supervisor maybe should be for voltage only?
this is demonstrate it :
try to do WIRED AND with Pullup, and then this input will drive the IC Supervisor and then stay the reset low with more t1 mS.

